# MacOS SwiftUI, how to prevent window close action

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

So I have a swiftUI application, at some point I create a NSWindow and assign the contentView, like this:

```swift
        // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Add token window
        // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        let configurationView = ConfigurationView().environmentObject(store)

        configurationWindow = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 500),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false
        )
        configurationWindow.center()
        configurationWindow.setFrameAutosaveName("BSchauer")
        let hostingController = NSHostingController(rootView: configurationView)
        configurationWindow.contentViewController = hostingController
        configurationWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        configurationWindow.setIsVisible(false)
    ... 
   // later on in the code
   @objc func toggleConfigurationWindow() {
        if self.configurationWindow.isVisible {
            self.configurationWindow.setIsVisible(false)
            if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
                self.popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
            }
        } else {
            self.configurationWindow.setIsVisible(true)

            self.configurationWindow.contentViewController?.view.window?.becomeKey()
        }
    }
```

You see that the way I interact with the window to present it to the user is via the visible flag, now the problem is when the window is shown and closed via the close button on the top bar, the window get somehow unmounted(?) and the next time the user tries to interact with the app and re-open the window I get a segmentation fault.

One of the things I tried was to instead of setting the visibility to false, just re-create the window again, but I still get the segmentation error.

All the previous answers I found are dealing with the old way of dealing with the NSViewController and overriding the `windowShouldClose` method, but I cannot seem to get that working.

TL:DR: When the user presses the red close button on the window, instead of the window getting destroyed I just want to set its visibility to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work, no need to set the contentViewController, you can use the standard contentView:

```swift
configurationWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: configurationView)
```

and to disable the window getting released when closed:

```swift
configurationWindow.isReleasedWhenClosed = false
```

I would still be interested in knowing when the window closed, to maybe perform an action afterwards, but this still solves my problem